# From the django tutorial was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'

Tags: python, django

From [the django tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/creating-and-running-your-first-django-project.html#d28041e21)

```
 was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
```

What is this statement really doing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is in reference to the admin section of django.

In the admin section corresponding to models, each models has a property called [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), which control which fields are displayed on the change list (list display of all the objects) page of the admin.

Now, if you wish to change the default sort order for `was_published_recently` in the `list_display` you can do so by setting the `admin_order_field` attribute.

So, in the example:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

You are adding a custom column called `was_published_recently` and specifying the sort order to be the database field `pub_date` when the "sort" option for the column `was_published_recently` is clicked.

You can understand this better by scrolling down to the information pertaining to `admin_order_field` in [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: This answer is almost perfect, but the code you quoted is not what creates the custom column for `was_published_recently`. The code that does is in `polls/admin.py` under the class `PollAdmin`. It's the line: `list_display = ('question', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')`. The code you showed (from `poll/models.py`) modifies the default state of that column.